# git & hugo - problem with creating git submodule to github

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, hugo

According to [this](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/) instruction, I entered the following into git,

```
git submodule add -b master https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<USERNAME>.github.io.git public
```

but `'public' does not have a commit checked out` appears as result.

I am quite new to this field, so I need explanations on some basic things. What exactly needs to be done with the `public` directory, and what should I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided shows you how to keep hugo files and the generated website files separated in different repos, i.e. the code in **github.com/username/blog** and website in **github.com/username/username.github.io**.

I feel that all this seems too complicated to you. The simplest way to serve a hugo website is by using only one repository. Just follow this:

1. create a repository named **username.github.io**
2. make your hugo site in this repo
3. run **hugo build**. This will generate the static website in a **public** folder.
4. Commit and push changes. The static files in the **public** folder will be automatically served.